# Date input in form is mapping to US Date Format, not UK, in an MVC4 Controller's parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, asp.net-mvc-4, date-format, html-input

I have a simple date input box:

```
<form
 ...
    Start Date:
    <input type="date" name="startDate" />
```

Which maps to a parameter in a Controller Method (MVC 4)

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? StartDate...
```

All was fine and dandy in the world of Firefox & Chrome which renders a nice little calendar picker but IE8 is not such a user friendly place....

IE8 renders a textbox for you to laboriously input a date string e.g. "11/08/2013"
Then the magical MVC URL encoding model binding thingy-mabob maps this to an American date i.e. the 8th of November.

How can I specify that this is to be mapped in the UK format? Am I going to have to extend a model binder class or something?

Comment: `<input type="date" />` is HTML5 which IE has awful support for and you won't even get a date picker in IE10.  So are you saying when using Chrome or Firefox the date is correctly bound in the UK format on the server side?

Comment: yea, exactly. I've resorted to changing the input type to text and writing my own function to try and parse a string input to UK date, not very elegant!

Comment: What about using the jQuery datepicker instead of relying on the input type date, since it's only partially supported.  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Also, do you have the current culture of the application set to the UK?